# Net Core Debugging Error: Evaluating the function timed out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, selenium-webdriver, .net-core

Having transitioned Selenium Tests to dotnet core 2.1 I am receiving the errors like:

> "Evaluating the function 'OpenQA.Selenium.Support.Events.EventFiringWebDriver.CurrentWindowHandle.get' timed out and needed to be aborted in an unsafe way.

I have followed answers from other questions which suggest turning off resharper, and turning on "use managed compatibility mode" & "use legacy c# and VB expression emulators" in the Visual Studio 2019 options. None of these allow the debugging evaluation to work in netcore2.1

**If I change the project to target net461 the issue goes away and debugging evaluations work correctly**. I was wondering why this is and if there were any working solutions for the issue aside from turning off debugging evaluations.

**Update:** After more inspection it appears to be caused by having a event attached which does some logging. For my use case this logging does not need to be enabled in debug mode so I am able to get around the issue, but I am still curious why this takes place. 
Below is a reproducible example.

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        using (var driver = new EventFiringWebDriver(
            new ChromeDriver(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())))
        {
            driver.ExceptionThrown += Driver_ExceptionThrown;
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://google.com"); //inspect driver here
            Assert.True(driver.FindElement(By.Id("gsr")).Displayed);
        }
    }

    private void Driver_ExceptionThrown(object sender, WebDriverExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        //Even though this even is ever called,
        //being attached causes the error when attempting to view the driver above.
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anything you can share about what the code is doing, or is there a minimum repeatable version of the code which causes the issue?

Comment: @JamieTaylor I have tracked down what seems to cause it and added it to the question. It appears to be caused by an attached event on EventFiringWebDriver, even if it is not called during the execution.